# How do I merge same ids and add their expense from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

1. Find the top paying user
2. Sort users according to descending order of their usage. If usage count is the same, then sort on userId ascending.
3. Total amount spent by users.

   ```
   [
   {userId: 1, balanceUsed: 180}, 
   {userId: 2, balanceUsed: 160}, 
   {userId: 1, balanceUsed: 250}, 
   {userId: 3, balanceUsed: 170}, 
   {userId: 2, balanceUsed: 220},
   {userId: 5, balanceUsed: 170},
   {userId: 4, balanceUsed: 230},
   {userId: 4, balanceUsed: 320},
   ]

   Ans:
   1 → userId (userId 1)
   2 → userId 4 (550), userId 1 (430), userId 2 (380), userId 3 (170), user 5 (170)
   3 → 1700
   ```

I have got the solution to the 3rd question by using the reduce method. How do I merge users with the same ids and add their expenses?

Comment: Haha not really. I failed to figure the answer during an interview today and hence the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get distinct userIds :

```
var uniquesUserIds = [...new Set(initial.map(m => m.userId))];
```

Then you only have to sum their balances :

```
var groupedUsers = [];
uniquesUserIds.forEach(userId => {
    let userIdSumedBalance = initial.filter(m => m.userId == userId).reduce(function(prev, cur){ return prev + cur.balanceUsed },0);
    groupedUsers.push(
    { 
        userId: userId, 
        balanceUsed: userIdSumedBalance
    });
});
```

That gives you :[image]

After that, to sort balances (highest to lowest) :

```
var descendingSorting = groupedUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.balanceUsed - a.balanceUsed;
});
```

For the top paying user :

```
var topPayingUser = groupedUsers[0];
```

Full code :

```
var initial = [
{userId: 1, balanceUsed: 180}, 
{userId: 2, balanceUsed: 160}, 
{userId: 1, balanceUsed: 250}, 
{userId: 3, balanceUsed: 170}, 
{userId: 2, balanceUsed: 220},
{userId: 5, balanceUsed: 170},
{userId: 4, balanceUsed: 230},
{userId: 4, balanceUsed: 320},
];

var uniquesUserIds = [...new Set(initial.map(m => m.userId))];
var groupedUsers = [];
uniquesUserIds.forEach(userId => {
    let userIdSumedBalance = initial.filter(m => m.userId == userId).reduce(function(prev, cur){ return prev + cur.balanceUsed },0);
    groupedUsers.push(
    { 
        userId: userId, 
        balanceUsed: userIdSumedBalance
    });
});

var descendingSorting = groupedUsers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.balanceUsed - a.balanceUsed;
});

var topPayingUser = groupedUsers[0];
console.log(topPayingUser);

console.log(descendingSorting);
```

Comment: Thank you. Got what I missed.